# Is using not equal <> sign in sql statement is poor programming practice?

Tags: sql

Is using the not equal `<>` sign in a **SQL** statement poor programming practice?

I have three values in a table column type.  The values can be 0, 1, or 2. 
Which SQL statement is better?

1) WHERE type <> 2
2) WHERE type in (0,1)

Comment: better the first for me...

Comment: type can not be null.

Comment: Based on indexing strategy the 2nd one is better since the list of values not equal to 2 is far greater than searching for 2 values in the index

Answer (score 6):

Neither is better than the other. Once you introduce a new type you might have to change one statement or the other.

An example: Let's say the type means "who pays".

- 0 = supplier pays
- 1 = client pays
- 2 = our selling department pays

So our query means "we don't pay". When introducing

- 3 = our buying department pays

then you'd have to change

```
WHERE type <> 2
```

to

```
WHERE type NOT IN (2,3)
```

When introducing

- 3 = other dealer pays

then you'd have to change the other query from

```
WHERE type IN (0,1)
```

to

```
WHERE type IN (0,1,3)
```

If you want to make it super-correct, you have a lookup table:

```
type  meaning                       wepay
0     supplier pays                 false
1     client pays                   false
2     our selling department pays   true
```

And the query:

```
WHERE type NOT IN (select type from types where wepay = true)
```

or

```
WHERE type IN (select type from types where wepay = false)
```

Again, it doesn't matter which of the two options to choose.

Comment: does extra data in sql worth avoiding altering code? also, isnt `... IN ( SELECT...` significantly slower? just asking

Comment: Generally additional data should never mean you have to change your queries. (Well, you cannot always avoid it, but this still serves as a good rule.) And no, a subquery on a small lookup table shouldn't have any impact on execution speed worth mentioning.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14565/mysql-subquery-slows-down-drastically-but-they-work-fine-independently